# Why Travis CI cannot read any public commits from GitHub?

Tags: github, travis-ci

For exmaple I have a public repository [datetime_tag_helper](https://github.com/swordray/datetime_tag_helper) with a .travis.yml file. I visit https://travis-ci.org/swordray/datetime_tag_helper , sign in and turn on building option. The page shows `There are no builds for this repository.` and blank Build History / Pull Requests / Branch Summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your GitHub repository isn't building because your`.travis.yml` is invalid. It looks like you want to build with Ruby version 2, in which  case your `.travis.yml` should look like this:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.1.0
```

You can read up more about ruby on travis-ci [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/).

Comment: You are right. `rvm install 2` not supported any more.